# failure_msg = 'Expected a constant of EXPECTED_BAKE_TIME with a value of 40.' self.assertEqual(EXPECTED_BAKE_TIME, 40, msg=failure_msg)

Tags: python

I am very new to Python and programming. I am trying to solve the second Python exercise on the website https://exercism.org/.

I am really struggling to understand why this first task fails. The code properly executes in VScode and I pass the 4/5 tests of this exercise using their online code editor. Why does the first test fail, while the other 4 succeed?

Here is my code:

```
def EXPECTED_BAKE_TIME():
    EXPECTED_BAKE_TIME = 40
    bake_time_remaining = 30
    elapsed_bake_time = (EXPECTED_BAKE_TIME - bake_time_remaining)
    print(elapsed_bake_time, "minutes to go") EXPECTED_BAKE_TIME()

def preparation_time_in_minutes():
    preparation_time_in_minutes = 2
    numbers_of_layers = (preparation_time_in_minutes * 4) # Multiply 4 layers
    print(numbers_of_layers, "layers of lasanga") preparation_time_in_minutes()

def elapsed_time_in_minutes():
    EXPECTED_BAKE_TIME = 40
    bake_time_remaining = 30
    elapsed_bake_time = (EXPECTED_BAKE_TIME - bake_time_remaining)
    preparation_time_in_minutes = 2
    numbers_of_layers = (preparation_time_in_minutes * 4) # Multiply 4 layers
    elapsed_time_in_minuites = (elapsed_bake_time + numbers_of_layers)

def bake_time_remaining():
    EXPECTED_BAKE_TIME = 40
    bake_time_remaining = 30
    elapsed_bake_time = (EXPECTED_BAKE_TIME - bake_time_remaining)
    preparation_time_in_minutes = 2
    numbers_of_layers = (preparation_time_in_minutes * 4) # Multiply 4 layers
    elapsed_time_in_minuites = (elapsed_bake_time + numbers_of_layers)
    print(elapsed_time_in_minuites, "Total cooking and preparation time") bake_time_remaining()
```

https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ryhsl.jpg

Comment: `EXPECTED_BAKE_TIME` can't refer to both a function, and a constant.

Comment: I have tried changing the variable `EXPECTED_BAKE_TIME` to `las_BAKE_TIME` on every line of my code, but the error persists.

Answer (score 0):

Welcome to python and programming in general.

The site is looking for a variable called `EXPECTED_BAKE_TIME`  which means you need define it.  The trick here is you don't need to create a function.

You can simply do this on the root of the file like so...

```py
EXPECTED_BAKE_TIME = 40

def bake_time_remaining():
    """Calculate the bake time remaining."""
    ...
```